# Is there a gulp plugin to run Laravel Artisan tasks?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-artisan

I haven't been able to find a gulp plugin whose purpose is to simply run Laravel Artisan tasks. It seems to me this would be useful.

I imagine it would be quite trivial, which makes me think it must exist.

I looked at [Laravel Elixir](https://github.com/laravel/elixir) but this doesn't seem to do what I want.

---

Not strictly on topic, but the problem at hand follows.

I briefly played with [gulp-shell](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell), [gulp-run](https://github.com/cbarrick/gulp-run), and [@eddieajau/shell](https://github.com/eddieajau/node-shell), and for a particular task don't seem to be having any luck: the command which runs just fine when run manually from the console seems to hang. `ps` shows it is running but apparently doing nothing. I'm probably missing something simple, but invoking shell commands from node always seems fiddly.

My current code in Coffee is this:

```
gulp.task 'twig', ->
    shell = require '@eddieajau/shell'
    shell.setLogger console.log
    return shell.exec 'php', ['artisan', 'twig:lint'],
        cwd: __dirname
```

This is supposed to return a promise, which `gulp.task` is supposed to notice and deal with. But when I run it it appears to hang.

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretend to know Coffeescript, however `gulp-shell` is blacklisted (meaning it doesn't do things "the gulp way").

[gulp-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec) may possibly do what you're looking for, however you don't specifically need that for a direct shell call.  Here's what I have in my gulpfile (non-coffeescript) to run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` after any of my models change:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('generate:ide-helper', function (cb) {
  exec('php artisan ide-helper:generate', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
```